# Refresh Gtk.StatusIcon in python

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to write a script that checks certain things and display a notification in the tray if something's wrong.  In this example, I'm looking at the age of a file.

What I can't seem to work out how to do is change the icon once gtk.main() is running.

```
import os, gtk
from time import time, sleep
from datetime import datetime

class HeartbeatTrayIcon(object):
    """
    Use GTK to create an object in the system tray
    and manipulate icon shown if there is an issue.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        rx = os.path.getmtime("test")
        self.statusIcon = gtk.StatusIcon()
        if (time() - rx) > (60*60*24):
            self.statusIcon.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL)
        else:
            self.statusIcon.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_APPLY)
        self.statusIcon.set_tooltip("Last heartbeat received at %s" % datetime.fromtimestamp(int(rx)).strftime('%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%Y'))

    def tray(self):
        gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = HeartbeatTrayIcon()
    i.tray()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only checking the file's age in the constructor for `HeartbeatTrayIcon`, so that code only runs once.

I'd suggest using [gobject.idle_add()](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--idle-add) to register a callback function that performs the check. That function will be called when the application is idle (i.e. when no higher-priority events exist in the queue):

```
import os, gtk, gobject
from time import time, sleep
from datetime import datetime

class HeartbeatTrayIcon(object):
    """
    Use GTK to create an object in the system tray
    and manipulate icon shown if there is an issue.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.statusIcon = gtk.StatusIcon()

    def check(self):
        rx = os.path.getmtime("test")
        if (time() - rx) > (60*60*24):
            self.statusIcon.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL)
        else:
            self.statusIcon.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_APPLY)
        self.statusIcon.set_tooltip("Last heartbeat received at %s" \
            % datetime.fromtimestamp(int(rx)).strftime('%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%Y'))
        return True

    def tray(self):
        gobject.idle_add(self.check)
        gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = HeartbeatTrayIcon()
    i.tray()
```

In passing, note that your heartbeat message does not seem to do what you're looking for: it will always print the modification time of the file, not the time of the last check. You might want to store the value returned by `time()`in a variable and use that instead of `rx`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks promising!  How often will the `gobject.idle_add(self.check)` run?

Comment: @jdborg, every time GTK processes its event queue, after all higher-priority events have been handled, until the function returns `false`. The default priority level should not result in too many calls.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't seem to get a change after touching "test" though, maybe we're returning false?

Comment: yep, adding return True has fixed it.  Nice!

Comment: @jdborg, yup, I was under the impression that returning `None` was not considered the same as returning `False`, but I was wrong. I'll update my answer with your fix.